# Strange behaviour after updating to Android Studio 3.1.1

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio-3.1

I've upgraded to Android Studio 3.1.1, now my project doesn't run and gives this error :

```
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
> ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.     at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>   at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException:
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.    at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:50)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:35)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:39)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:24)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:207)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:133)
>   at
> com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:125)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)     at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>   ... 32 more
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$project.andySDK"
        force "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$project.andySDK"
        force "com.android.support:support-v4:$project.andySDK"
        force "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:$project.andySDK"
        force "com.android.support:design:$project.andySDK"
        force "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$project.andySDK"
        force "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$project.andySDK"
        force "com.android.support:support-v13:$project.andySDK"
        force "net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.2.1"
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.myCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()
    buildToolsVersion project.myBuildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.c2x.yad"
        minSdkVersion project.myMinSdkVersion.toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion project.myTargetSdkVersion.toInteger()
        versionCode 3
        versionName "80"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "NoteAsan_" + defaultConfig.versionName);
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/hellmannmaicon/android" }
    maven { url 'http://guardian.github.com/maven/repo-releases' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    // RecyclerView

    //    compile 'com.rm:freedrawview:1.0.1'

    // this is from main developer
//    compile 'com.github.codekidX:storage-chooser:2b286fc'
//    compile 'com.github.codekidX:storage-chooser:1.0.31'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':colorpickerview')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    //    compile 'com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioRecorder:0.2.0'
    compile project(':AudioRecorder')



    implementation ('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.11.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }


//    compile 'com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioConverter:0.0.8'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$project.andySDK"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$project.andySDK"
    implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$project.andySDK"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$project.andySDK"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$project.andySDK"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:$project.andySDK"
//    implementation 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.myinnos:AppFontChanger:1.0'
//    implementation 'br.com.forusers.heinsinputdialogs:input-dialogs-library:0.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.matthiasrobbers:shortbread:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.vlad1m1r990:Lemniscate:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    implementation 'com.evernote:android-job:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.matthiasrobbers:shortbread-compiler:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.alirezaafkar:sundatepicker:2.0.6'

    implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.hamsaadev:RTLMaterialSpinner:V1.0.1'

    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.0'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'

    implementation 'com.aromajoin.library:actionsheet:0.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Clean-Rebuild-Restart at first . May i know what `buildToolsVersion` ?

Comment: Did you check error in debug info or event log?

Comment: why `compile` ?? change it to `implementation` and also there are some error check your project thoroughly ...

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya build tools version is 27.0.3

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya dexOptions { incremental false } has no effect

Comment: @AVEbrahimi Check https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#3-1-0